# SQL Server Configuration Manager- Services missing

Tags: sql-server, ssms, configurationmanager

I've had an instance of SQL Server (Express) installed on a local CPU, working fine, that today suddenly is encountering an error during connection in SSMS to the server.

[image: Error Message]

In following the steps from some discussions about this, in config manager, I see nothing showing for Services.

[image: Config Manager]

Discovery report shows this installed.

[image: Discovery Report]

Any ideas on what I need to do in order to link back again to the server?

Comment: Can you see the service in services?

Comment: No, in config manager, nothing is showing at all under services not even SQL agent etc.

Comment: Not in the configuration manager, in services.

Comment: Is this the only instance of SQL Server you have installed on your machine?

Comment: If you are referring to services.msc, no, it is not showing up (SQL Server)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue by running the Maintenance-Repair feature with the installation center and then I ran repair for SSMS on top of that. Not sure what happened still and am interested if anyone has any ideas.